# Sorting of paginator object through a model relation column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have three tables: `products`, `product_inventories` and `product_inventory_details`. The [ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) of each model is shown below,

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model{
    ...

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        ...,
        'title', 
        'selected_inventory_id', 
        ...
    ];

    /**
     * Get the inventories those belongs to this model.
     */
    public function inventory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductInventory');
    }

    /**
     * Get the selected product_inventory_detail that owns this model.
     */
    public function selected(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductInventoryDetail', 'id', 'selected_inventory_id');
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**ProductInventory Model**

```
class ProductInventory extends Model{
    ...
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id', 
        ...
    ];


    /**
     * Get the inventory_details those belongs to this model.
     */
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductInventoryDetail');
    }

    ...
}
```

**ProductInventoryDetail Model**

```
class ProductInventoryDetail extends Model{
    ...
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_inventory_id',  
        'price', 
        ...
    ];
}
```

I'm sorting and limiting the results through user input of *Sort by* dropdown and *Show per page* dropdown. When sorting by **Alphabetical: High to Low** option I'm running the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) method to order the results:

```
$products = $products->orderBy($sort['column'], $sort['order'])->paginate($limit);
```

Now with sorting by **Price**, I can't run the query builder method `orderBy()` since I'm not using joins and getting the data through relationship properties. Instead I'm using the Laravel's [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections) method to sort it out:

```
$products = $products->paginate($limit);

$products = $products->sortBy(function($prod, $key){
    return $prod->selected->price;
});
```

The above block is working fine if I don't use pagination methods. But, I need to use the [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination) as well since the user can also limit the results per page. I'm also using a `Paginator` object's method to append some parameters to each page URL:

```
$products->appends($paramsArr);
```

Since running the `sortBy()` method returns a collection instead of `Paginator` object, it's giving me `undefined method` exception.

**My Question**

> How can I sort the result set by price in my current scenario without having to implement the joins? Is there a way to achieve that??

Answer (score 1):

I would use `QueryBuilder` package of `Spatie`. It will make your life easier for creating sortable and filterable grid table. You use that package this way:

```
$query = Product::with(['inventory', 'selected']);
$products = \Spatie\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder::for($query)
    ->allowedFilters([
          'name' => 'name', // name column in the products DB table.
          'selected.price' => 'product_inventory_details.column_price', // price column in the product_inventory_details DB table.
     ])
     ->defaultSort('name')
     ->allowedSorts([
          'name',
          \Spatie\QueryBuilder\AllowedSort::custom('selected.price', new SortSelectedPrice())
     ])
     ->paginate(20)
     ->appends(request()->query());
```

External custom sort class looks like this:

```
 class SortSelectedPrice implements \Spatie\QueryBuilder\Sorts\Sort
 {
      public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
      {
           $direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
           $query->leftJoin('product_inventory_details', 'products.id', '=', 'product_inventory_details.product_id');
           $query->orderBy('product_inventory_details.column_price', direction);
      }
  }
```

Make sure your URL containing the query string like this for sorting name from A to Z and sorting price from 1xxxxxxxx to 0:

```
domain.com/products?sort=name,-selected.price
```

I installed the Spatie package using composer. Don't forget to do that.

Comment: Thanks O Conner, I will surely check it out and give it a read and try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle it without having to implement the joins. I added a new variable and stored the Paginator object's `items()` method result set into it.

```
$products = $products->paginate($limit);

$productItems = $products->items(); // returns the items array from paginator
```

And sort that particular variable instead of sorting the whole paginator object. That way my links and URLs are untouched and unmodified in the `$products` variable and the data of the products are in a separate variable.

```
if($sort['column'] == 'price'){
    if($sort['order'] == 'DESC'){
        $productItems = $products->sortByDesc(function($prod, $key){
            return $prod->selected->price;
        });
    } else{
        $productItems = $products->sortBy(function($prod, $key){
            return $prod->selected->price;
        });
    }
}
```

I also had to change my rendering variable from `$products` to `$productItems` and accessed the pagination links from the old `$products` variable.

```
@forelse ($productItems as $product)
    @include('site.components.product-grid')
@empty
    <div class="col text-center">...</div>
@endforelse

...

{{ $products->links() }}
```

*I'm posting it here for the community to benefit/discuss/criticize if there is a better way.*